# Join 2 randomly genreted list

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, random

I am trying to join 2 randomly generated list into one but its adding them element wise. Suppose I generated 2 list each with 2 random numbers I want my output list to be of numbers. For example:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.uniform(0,0.1, 2)
x2 = np.random.uniform(0,0.1, 2)

x = x1 + x2

print(x1)
print(x2)
print(x)
The output is: 
[0.06878713 0.03807816]
[0.01801809 0.06292975]
[0.08680523 0.10100791]

But I want my output as 
[0.06878713 0.03807816]
[0.01801809 0.06292975]
[0.06878713 0.03807816 0.01801809 0.06292975]
```

If I use append() or extend() its giving me: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'.

Comment: The problem is that you think they are lists but they are numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As listed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_join.asp), you would do the following:

```py
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.uniform(0,0.1, 2)
x2 = np.random.uniform(0,0.1, 2)

x = np.concatenate((x1, x2))

print(x1)
print(x2)
print(x)
```

The output is:

```
[0.09031488 0.0600346]
[0.03298771 0.08265562]
[0.09031488 0.0600346  0.03298771 0.08265562]
```